# Formal research on the social/psychological aspects of sites like Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I find it interesting that people tend to exchange work for recognition in a way that benefits "the collective". I know I'm not the first person to recognize this.

Have there been any formal research projects or something of the like?

Answer (score 4):

## An Analysis of the Stack Overflow Q&A Site

> This project analyzes a Question & Answer site for programmers, Stack
> Overflow, that dramatically improves on the utility and performance of
> Q&A systems for technical domains...
>
> ...
>
> Our analysis is based on the August 2010 Stack Exchange Data Dump
> (creative-commons licensed)...

[http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bjoern/projects/stackoverflow/](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebjoern/projects/stackoverflow/)

Comment: Great paper, George! Thanks a bunch for the link! My ex, and best friend, is on Psychopedagogy, and when I explain details of the Stack she is like *"Really?! That's cool..!"*